# C++ template for QList

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qlist

My template function:

```
template<typename TList, typename TItem>
void setIndex(TList &list, QString &selectedId)
{
    typename QList<TItem>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); iter++){
        if(iter->id() == selectedId){
            m_curItemIdx = iter - list.begin();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to call

`setIndex<>(list, selectedId);`

But this call makes an error.

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'setIndex' (...)
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'TItem'
```

So I tried

`setIndex<QList<Item>, Item>(list, selectedId);`

Then it worked. Still I don't clearly understand why the first one failed.

(edit)

In case of another function,

```
template<typename TList, typename TItem>
void addItem(TList &list, TItem &item)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    list << item;
    endInsertRows();
}
```

For this function,

`addItem<>(list, item)`

worked. I'm not suer what makes the difference

Comment: You have to specify the template instances between `< >` so the compiler knows, for which classes it should generate the templated code. In your first example this is empty, so it doesn't know which class TItem and TLIst should be

Comment: using templates requires to know the type of the arguments in the compilation time and you need to pass them into the `< >`

Comment: Does `setIndex(list, selectedId);` work? The template arguments should be deduced from the function parameters.

Comment: thanks for you comments, I edited to compare.

Comment: Similar situation, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890027/qlist-generic-join-function-with-template/57896115

Answer (score 1):

You probably want (so deduction can happen):

```
template<typename TItem>
void setIndex(const QList<TItem>& list, const QString &selectedId)
{
    typename QList<TItem>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter) {
        if (iter->id() == selectedId) {
            m_curItemIdx = iter - list.begin();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
template <typename Container>
void setIndex(const Container& c, const QString& selectedId)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(c.begin(),
                           c.end(),
                           [&](const auto& item){ return item.id() == selectedId });
    if (it != c.end()) {
        m_curItemIdx = std::distance(c.begin(), it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! TList was useless, as you guided. I edited the post to compare with another case.